# getting gps updates in constant location also?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am in constant location but i am getting gps updates continuosly and plot the line in constant location also.How to stop gps updates in constant location?

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                        if(latitude>0.0&&longitude>0.0){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude
                                        + "\nLong: " + longitude,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        RouteManager.sourceMarker(getActivity(), latLng,
                                googleMap, markpos, 0);
                        markpos++;

                        points.add(latLng);// addding Latlng to points array

                        Log.d("pointssize", "pointskal--->" + points.size());
                        Double distance = 0.0;
                        //if more than one point we can find duplicate points getting or not,if getting duplicate we remove duplicate point
                        if (points.size() > 1) {
                            // 2.comparing prev and nextlatitudes and longitudes
                            boolean duplicate = routemanage.isDuplicate(points,
                                    googleMap);

                            if (duplicate) {
                                points.remove(points.size() - 1);
                                Log.d("pointssize", "pointskalremnoveafter--->"
                                        + points.size());
                                duplicate = false;
                            } else {
                                int size = points.size();
                                //if not duplicate we can find out the distance

                                distance = routemanage.findDistanceOnRoute(
                                        points.get(size - 2).latitude,
                                        points.get(size - 2).longitude,
                                        points.get(size - 1).latitude,
                                        points.get(size - 1).longitude);
                                Log.d("sorrry", "distance initaial" + distance);


                                if (distance < 1) {
                                    //if distance is less than 1 meter we simply remove the point

                                    points.remove(points.size() - 1);
                                    Log.d("pointssize",
                                            "distance lessthan 1--->"
                                                    + points.size());
                                } else {
                                    // we have to check distance >1 m we can draw the route
                                    sum = sum + distance;
                                    RouteManager.drawRoute(getActivity(),
                                            points, googleMap, sum);
                                    Log.d("sorrry", "sorry dad sum" + sum);
                                    settingmaprunDetails(points.get(size - 1),
                                            sum);
                                }

                                duplicate = true;

                            }// else
                        }// if


                        //if points size is <=1 we can't draw the route
                        else if (points.size() == 1) {
                            settingmaprunDetails(points.get(0), 0.0);
                        }

                    }
```

I am attaching screen shot please see once and give me solution to avoid this clumsy ness of plotting the route on google map.

[image]

Comment: You have to filter out small movements caused by signal jitter.  All GPS devices suffer from this.

Comment: I am drawing line if distance is greater than 1 meter.but getting same problem.can you tell how to avoid small movements.

Comment: Consumer GPS accuracy is > 5m without long term integration.

Answer (score 0):

you can set [Smallest Displacement](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) somewhere in your `GPSTracker` (where the `locationManager`) is created. For example:

```
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Set the Smallest Displacement sets the minimum displacement between location updates in meters. By default this is 0. You can reduce the signal jitter using this with a reasonable value.